# Delete confirm with Sweet Alert 2 in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$wp->id}})" id="{{$wp->id}}" data-id="{{$wp->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

This is my jquery + ajax code:

```
function deleteConfirmation(id) {
    swal.fire({
        title: "Usunąć wypis?",
        text: "Upewnij się czy chcesz usunąć ten wypis!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonText: "Tak, usuń go!",
        cancelButtonText: "Nie, anuluj!",
        reverseButtons: !0
    }).then(function (e) {

        if (e.value === true) {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{url('/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy')}}/" + id,
                data:  {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (results) {

                    if (results.success === true) {
                        swal.fire("Usunięto wypis!", results.message, "success");
                    } else {
                        swal.fire("Wystąpił błąd!", results.message, "error");
                    }
                }.then(function() {
                            location.reload();
                        });
            });

        } else {
            e.dismiss;
        }

    }, function (dismiss) {
        return false;
    })
}
```

This is my Laravel Controller function destroy()

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $delete = \App\Wypisy::where('id', $id)->delete();
    return back();
    // check data deleted or not
    if ($delete == 1) {
        $success = true;
        $message = "Wypis został usunięty !";
    } else {
        $success = true;
        $message = "Wypisu nie znaleziono";
    }

    //  Return response
    return response()->json([
        'success' => $success,
        'message' => $message,
    ]);
    return back();
}
```

when I click the button, show me the confirmation window, and when I click, remove it, I will receive the message jquery.min.js: 2 POST http://localhost:8000/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/3 404 (Not Found) does not happen. As I copy the link above, the removal method works correctly in Laravel. What am I doing wrong ? Any tips?

Laravel 5.8, jquery 3.4.1

Comment: If you copy the link, and paste it in, is it not a GET request then? Are you sure your get/post http settings are setup correctly?

Comment: this is my route :  Route::post('/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy/{id}', 'WypisyController@destroy');

Comment: Change the `post` with a `get` in the route

Comment: OFF TOPIC: Your controller is a little bit confusing  you are returning `back()` after the `->delete()`

Comment: Your 404 message has a different URL than what you've posted in code. One of these things is wrong. It's preferable to name your routes and then use `route()` helper to show the URLs.

Comment: @YJRB why would they change the route definition? The jQuery code is doing a POST.

Comment: @miken32 sorry I read badly !

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the `id` with `POST`

Your ajax function:

```
 // code ...
 type: 'POST',
      url: "{{url('/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy')}}",
      data:  {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "id": id},
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (results) {

// code ...
```

Your route:

```
Route::post('/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy', 'WypisyController@destroy');
```

Your Controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    //
    $id = $request->id;
    $delete = \App\Wypisy::where('id', $id)->delete();

    // code ...
```

Comment: If he pass the id in the url he need to change his route to get and his ajax function too

Comment: No, that's not the case. Look at any resource controller routes for examples of routes that are posted but still contain parameters in the URL.

Comment: OP is getting 404, not 405 (method not allowed) so the URL is altogether wrong. Probably a typo.

Comment: If you use post it's better to pass the `id` parameter in the `$request`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but for me when I do a delete like this it works

Answer (score 0):

when i change my code for this

```
 function deleteConfirmation(id) {
    swal.fire({
        title: "Usunąć wypis?",
        text: "Upewnij się czy chcesz usunąć ten wypis!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonText: "Tak, usuń go!",
        cancelButtonText: "Nie, anuluj!",
        reverseButtons: !0
    }).then(function (e) {

        if (e.value === true) {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{url('/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy')}}",
                data:  {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "id": id},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (results) {

                    if (results.success === true) {
                        swal.fire("Usunięto wypis!", results.message, "success");
                    } else {
                        swal.fire("Wystąpił błąd!", results.message, "error");
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            e.dismiss;
        }

    }, function (dismiss) {
        return false;
    })
}
```

i recive in console:

```
 jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/destroy 
 500 (Internal Server Error)
 send @ jquery.min.js:2
 ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
 (anonymous) @ (index):395
 Promise.then (async)
 ue.then @ sweetalert.all.js:1
 deleteConfirmation @ (index):390
 onclick @ (index):173
```

Comment: when i comeback to url: "{{route('wypisy.destroy', $wp->id)}}" + id,   data:  {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"}, i have response in console: POST http://localhost:8000/przedsiebiorca/wypisy/44 405 (Method Not Allowed)